# Specify a font family in Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-office-2010

Being a webdesigner, I wondered whether it is possible to specify a font-family for Word.

A webdesigner can specify a font-family, like so:

```
font-family: Lato, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
```

So when a user doesn't have a font installed, the next font in line will be rendered. I am looking for something like this in Office, more specifically Word.

Does this exist?

Comment: *Font family* does not mean what you think. It's either something like *Arial* or *Helvetica Neue Ultra Light*, depending on who you ask (and in what language). What you do show in your example is *multiple font families and a generic fallback*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter has already pointed out, you're not talking about font families. I'll use the term fallback fonts.

Simple answer: no. Word is designed around assigning specific fonts to text. It does not have a way for you to specify fallback fonts. Now, if you export your file as HTML (don't; Word-generated HTML is weird and full of propriety cruft), Word will generate HTML with fallback fonts that make sense for the specific fonts you used, but you have no control over what the fallback fonts are.

If you ignore the use case of Word as an HTML editor (and you should) this makes perfect sense. Word is not supposed to be a document reader, though many people use it that way. Its documents are meant to be "printed out" either on an actual printer or as a PDF file or other edocument. You obviously don't have to worry about font availability once a page is printed out (originally the only output that Word supported!) and a PDF file can contain embedded fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does exist!! In microsoft office 2007 look right under Home tab (but you can select only one font at the time). Not sure about other versions though. Hope it helps:)

Comment: I'm working with 2010 so I can't check that due to the ribbon layout. But, I don't just want to change the font, I want to select a number of possibilities so that when one font is not found, the next one is used.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help. When authoring in Word, you can only choose from fonts which are installed. From the standpoint of font substitution when viewing, there are some choices in Options > Advanced.

[image]

and also some choices in Options > Advanced > Web Options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Word was this for?

Comment: 2010, as the question asked for.

Comment: Doh! Of course.